# how to delete line of header in specific page?

Tags: texworks

In my report, I add header where I show my current chapter name:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\headrulewidth{0pt}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\bsc{\chaptername~\thechapter{}. }#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} \\line of separation
\lhead[\textsl{\rightmark}]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
```

My problem exist in list of graphics page,`{\pagestyle{plain} \listoffigures}` the line of separation is always there and I cant delete it. How can I do it??

[image]

Comment: Try `\pagestyle{plain}\thispagestyle{plain}`

Comment: No it didn't work for me

Comment: First, it is `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` and you need to put it into `\fancypagestyle{plain}{..}` along with the rest of the stuff on page 11 of the fancyhdr manual.